# Error when updating fullCalendar whit Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fullcalendar

I have a calendar (fullCalendar.io), after creating / updating an event, I save in the BD and refresh the calendar:

```
function refreshEvent()
{
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
};
```

I have no problems with this.

I implemented socket.io, to refresh all the other clients, but when I run refreshEvent ()

in **SourceBrowser** "*there was an error while fetching events!*"

in **Browser2**, update without problem

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      windowResize: function(view) {},
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaWeek'
      },
      allDaySlot: false,scrollTime: '07:00:00',defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      weekNumbers: true,navLinks: true,editable: true,eventLimit: true,
      droppable: true,
      eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
        var obj = {}
        obj.cAccion = 'M'
        obj.nId = event.id
        obj.cTitle = event.title;
        obj.cStart = assembleFullDate(event.start._i,'start');
        obj.cEnd = assembleFullDate(event.start._i,'end');
        obj.cClassName = selectClass(event.title);
        obj.idEvent = 0;
        var rF = cudObj("/cudEvents",obj);
      },
      eventReceive: function(event) {
        var obj = {}
        obj.cAccion = 'C'
        obj.nId = 0
        obj.cTitle = event.title;
        obj.cStart = assembleFullDate(event.start._i,'start');
        obj.cEnd = assembleFullDate(event.start._i,'end');
        obj.cClassName = selectClass(event.title);
        obj.idEvent = event.id;
        var rF = cudObj("/cudEvents",obj);
      },
      eventSources: [
        {
          url: '/dataSimulation',
          type: 'GET',
          error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
          }
        }
      ],
      businessHours: {
        dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
        start: '07:00',
        end: '18:00',
      },
    });
```

I got idea that it will give error because of it try to get much data frequently and it is not able to handle instantly till previous data get completed.Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: ` error: function() { console.log(err); }` ?

Comment: @MukeshSharma 
"Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first."

according to the error is the connection to the BD ... thanks, I thought the error was in fullCalendar